# Android ArrayList - Same numbers

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a little problem here.
I'm retrieving columns out of my database and save them in an ArrayList

```
public ArrayList<String> getColumn(String table, String column) {

    ArrayList<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor result = db.query(true, table,
            new String[] { column }, null, null, null, null,
            null, null);

    if (result.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            columns.add(result.getString(result
                    .getColumnIndex(column)));
        } while (result.moveToNext());
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    return columns;
}
```

Some columns in my Database have the same entry (i.e. 0)
In my case right now the Database has three rows.
So when I read the Arrays its:

```
[2, 3, 6]
[2, 4, 8]
[456, 45645, 6544]
[1, 2]
[2]
[1.12.2015, 31.11.2016, 29.10.2014]
[0]
```

But it should be:

```
[2, 3, 6]
[2, 4, 8]
[456, 45645, 6544]
[1, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2]
[1.12.2015, 31.11.2016, 29.10.2014]
[0, 0, 0]
```

As you can see, if the numbers match it just adds it ones to the ArrayList.
Is there any way I can prevent it from doing it?

Edit:
For better explanation

Database:
[image]

and here is how i retrieve and display the Arrays:

```
ArrayList<String> a, ac, b, c, d, e, f;

        a = myDb.getColumn(DATABASE_TABLE, DBSuche.VAR_PKW_MARKE);
        ac = myDb.getColumn(DATABASE_TABLE, DBSuche.VAR_PKW_MODELL);
        b = myDb.getColumn(DATABASE_TABLE, DBSuche.VAR_PKW_FAHRZEUGPREIS);
        c = myDb.getColumn(DATABASE_TABLE, DBSuche.VAR_PKW_FAHRZEUGTYP);
        d = myDb.getColumn(DATABASE_TABLE, DBSuche.VAR_PKW_GETRIEBE);
        e = myDb.getColumn(DATABASE_TABLE, DBSuche.VAR_PKW_ERSTZULASSUNG);
        f = myDb.getColumn(DATABASE_TABLE, DBSuche.VAR_PKW_COUNTER);

        int i = 0;

        for ( ; i <= a.size() - 1; i++) {
            Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(a));
            Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(ac));
            Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(b));
            Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(c));
            Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(d));
            Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(e));
            Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(f));
            Log.e(TAG, i + " | " + a.size());
            Log.e("---------------", "----------");
        }
```

Comment: This is strange, first, you have an array of string, so the shown output doesn't match. You probably use some `Set` somewhere. Please  post a [mcve]

Comment: If you print result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(column)), it showing the right values ?

Comment: post your query

Comment: try changing the `boolean` in you `query` to `false`

Comment: Before checking the elements added in the arraylist, check what your query is returning

Comment: Also to address a comment to a specific user, use `@name_of_user` as first entry in the comment box

Comment: Use Set in place of ArrayList.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the `boolean` in your query to `false`

From android developer website :

```
Cursor query (boolean distinct, 
                String table, 
                String[] columns, 
                String selection, 
                String[] selectionArgs, 
                String groupBy, 
                String having, 
                String orderBy, 
                String limit, 
                CancellationSignal cancellationSignal)
```

> distinct   boolean: true if you want each row to be unique, false otherwise.

Read this [SQLiteDatabase.query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.CancellationSignal))